# delete images containing specific word in its name using python

Tags: python, regex

In the directory there are multiple images with names:
[image: image names]

I want to delete all images with "340" in it using a python code.
Assuming that the images are in desktop/images/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to use Python and can't just use your shell (in bash it would just be `rm desktop/images/*340*`)

But in Python I think the shortest way would be

```py
import os, glob

for file in glob.glob("desktop/images/*340*"):
    os.remove(file)
```

or even:

```py
import os, glob

[os.remove(file) for file in glob.glob("desktop/images/*340*")]
```

Comment: I agree, one line of shell would be much faster, but maybe OP doesn't have a linux/unix system or wants to automate with just Python or doesn't know how to use `cron` job just yet.

Comment: In any case the same advice I pointed out in another answer comment, _What If_ there is another files with 340 inside the name. It could be better to be a bit more explicit with `*_340.jpg` and `*_340.png`

Comment: The OP's requirement is to delete all files which match a pattern. If they really wanted a different pattern, that's on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example, you'll have to adjust the code for your correct directory:

```
import os
import re

for file in os.listdir("Desktop/Images"):
    if re.search("340.*?\.jpg$", file):
        os.remove("Desktop/Images/" + file)
        print("Deleted " + file)
    else:
        print("No match for " + file)
```

Comment: The OP did ask for a regex solution, but you don't need regular expressions for this; `if "340" in file:`

Comment: @tripleee Correct, I thought of that too.

Comment: Your solution seems correct but _What If_ there is another file with "340" inside their name? It would be better to be more specific, since `remove` could permanently delete. Maybe more strict regex/`if _ in file:` condition, something `"_340.jpg"` and `"_340.png"`